# Arc length of function - confused about particular u-substitution in integral

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution, arc-length

I am trying to teach myself how to compute the arc length of a function through a [textbook](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Extensions-Calculus-Mathematics-Project-Further/dp/0521377021), and I am stuck on how they did a particular integral substitution in a worked example.

I'll provide the specific line of working I am stuck to provide relevant information quickly. I'll follow with my working, and then provide the context of the question below if necessary.

**Where I am stuck**

I am unsure how to get from:

$$\int_1^3\sqrt{1+4t^2}\,dt$$

to, as the book puts it exactly:

$$\int{\frac{1}{2}\cosh^2u \,du}$$

They say they are
putting $2t$ = $\sinh u$.

I am unsure of how to get to this line using that substitution. (I am also unsure why the bounds of integration are gone, I originally assumed out of convenience but different bounds due to the substitution are being used later in the example.)

**My attempt**

$\int_1^3\sqrt{1+4t^2}\,dt$

Using $2t$ = $\sinh u\Rightarrow2\,dt = \cosh u \Rightarrow dt = \frac{\cosh u}{2}\,du$.

$\int_1^3\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+\sinh^2 u} \cosh u \,du$

Using $\sqrt{1+\sinh^2 u} \equiv \cosh^2 u$:

$\int_1^3\frac{1}{2}\cosh^2u \cosh u \,du$

$\frac{1}{2}\int_1^3\cosh^3u \,du$

Clearly there is an issue here, as I have arrived at $\cosh^3u$ instead of $\cosh^2u$ (and potentially different bounds of integration.) I'm not sure if there's an error in my working and/or if there's some different integration technique that I need to apply here.

**More context**

The example relates to finding an arc length of the function $y = x^2$ from $(1, 1)$ to $(3, 9)$. This length $s$is being worked out using: $$\frac{ds}{dt} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}$$

The function is parameterised: $x = t$, y = $t^2$. I am then confident in using this to find that:

$$s = \int_1^3\sqrt{1+4t^2} \,dt$$

If there is any more information I should provide please do not hesitate to answer. (Also, I've not posted here much so if there is any error in my MathJax formatting please correct it *as well as* telling me what I should have done instead. Thank you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the correction: $$\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(u)} \equiv \cosh^{\color{red}{1}} (u)$$as $\cosh^2(u)-\sinh^2(u)=1$.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Silly mistake!

Comment: @Robin Happens with most people.

Comment: Just approved the answer, it made me wait a while before doing it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Robin You’re welcome.